# At which step of pipeline should I split data into train and test for time series analysis?

Tags: time-series, python

Should I split the data into train and test before cleaning the data or should I split the data at the very end of the pipeline process i.e. once the features are created? Would it create any difference? I know that I have to use Walk forward model building approach but I am confused at what stage I should split the data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You’d be better off posting this on the Data Science stack.

Comment: The general practice is to clean and then split the data into train and test thereof. Any new test data you receive must also go through the same process of cleaning before being tested.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if it's an actual cleaning (missing data, wrong data, exceptional outliers) or stylized facts cleaning (i.e. smoothing or filtering, seasonal adjustment). Though, the general rule is to clean first. Results are likely to be different, but it ultimately depends on how much you've clean.

Comment: Why exactly is it a "general rule"? Who said it is?

Answer (score 0):

Feature engineering may leak all kind of information, so if you do it first and then split, you can end up with a model that does good on test data, but not on real data. So I don't agree with the other answer, you should **split first**.

Answer (score 0):

If your data for training and test are not in the same format, then this could cause issues when the model attempts to interpret features for the test set.

As an example, suppose one of the features is a categorical variable in string format.

```
apple
banana
blueberries
cucumber
orange
```

Part of the data cleaning process appends numbers to these categories:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Should this procedure only be carried out for the training data but not the test data, then the model being used to generate output will not be able to interpret the data properly.

While it depends on the specific situation, one generally wants to implement data cleaning procedures before choosing to conduct a train/test split.